# javascript on scrolltop animate div height + background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm building my own photography website with a header that changes when the user scrolls down the page. The HTML menu/header looks like this:

```
<div id="menu" class="fluid">
header/menu content
</div>
```

Using CSS I created a transparent black background and gave the menu a height:

```
#menu {
height: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Now, using JavaScript, I made this header collapse to 75 pixels when the user scrolls down more than 5 pixels. When you scroll back to the top it goes back to 100px. The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
<script>
// Minimize menu on scroll
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > 5) {
      $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "75px"},150);
  }
  else {
      $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "100px"},150);
  }
  });
</script>
```

I am looking for an easy way to change the background transparency together with the height of the menu and was hoping anyone knew what code to use for it. I have no experience with JavaScript, only with HTML and CSS code.

Thanks in advance, and I'm sorry if this question was asked before (I couldn't find it using my keywords).

~ Elmigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make annimation just using css transition :
by example above I've just added transition property on opacity then 
I managed to change it on scrolling.

not that I set and rgb color value instead of rgba , also set opacity to 0
.1;

```js
// Minimize menu on scroll
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scrollTop > 5) {
    $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "50px"},150);
    //$('#menu').css("opacity","0.8");
    $('div').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)')
}
else {
    $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "100px"},150);
    //$('#menu').css("opacity","0.1");
    $('div').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)')
}
});
```

```css
#menu {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition:background-color 0.5s ease;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="fluid">
<p>gggg<p>
</div>
text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text
<br>text<br>text<br>text
```

Comment: Great solution, except... this code changes opacity for the full menu div including the border and all of its content. I only want to change the background opacity when you scroll down. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Great , I uunderstand your need , please see my edited answer :) 

If that swwet you please up and mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class

```
.darkerbg {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Add/remove it at the appropriate times

```
if (scrollTop > 5) {
  $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "75px"},150);
  $('#menu').addClass('darkerbg');
}
else {
  $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "100px"},150);
  $('#menu').removeClass('darkerbg');
}
```

---

Additionally, you could move all this into CSS by changing the height with the class like so:

```
.menu {
  //various properties
  transform: all 0.1s; // this provides the animation effect
}
.big {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.small {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Then do this with the JS:

```
if (scrollTop > 5 && !$('#menu).hasClass('small')) {
  $('#menu').removeClass('big'); //just incase it is there
  $('#menu').addClass('small');
} else if (scrollTop <= 5 && !$('#menu).hasClass('big')) {
  $('#menu').removeClass('small'); //just incase it is there
  $('#menu').addClass('big');
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. Never thought of the addClass. Going to try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I would say amflare's answer is almost correct. I'd remove the `animate` from the javascript altogether and do it this way:

CSS:

```
.darkerbg {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#menu {
height: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if (scrollTop > 5) {
  $('#menu').addClass('darkerbg');
}
else {
  $('#menu').removeClass('darkerbg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the changing of the `background-color`, you can use `jquery-ui` plugin: [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/animate/). I find it very useful and it's workink fine and pretty.

For example:

First, include the `jQuery UI` in your's project:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="></script>
```

And change the `Javascript` content to:

```
<script>
// Minimize menu on scroll
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 5) {
        $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "75px", backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"}, 150);
    }
    else {
        $('#menu').stop().animate({height: "100px", backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"},150);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This was the first thing that came up in me to do. Unfortunately this did not work (the background opacity does not change). Is there anything I need to do in CSS to make this work?

Comment: @EloyMillenniaGotjé What does not working? what does the console prints? Is the height changes?